# How to add text when exporting a chart in highcharts?

Tags: charts, highcharts, ionic3

I have a line chart and I can export chart to pdf or image.

I wonder if I can put some additional text below the chart, only when I export it? Such as additional information about the chart data.

I'd like to export the chart that looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lNEo.png)

I use Ionic v3.

If possible, I would like to see a sample code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/fje0agem/

I created some space for the text area by manipulating `chart.height` and `chart.marginBottom` in `exporting.chartOptions`. I adjusted the position of some elements (credits, legend) by changing their `y` offset.

Text and lines can be rendered via `SVGRenderer`. `load` event is a proper place to put the code responsible for that.

```
  chart: {
    height: 300,
    width: 600
  },

  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        height: 600,
        marginBottom: 300,
        events: {
          load: function() {
            var renderer = this.renderer;

            renderer.path(['M', 30, 385, 'L', 570, 385, 'Z']).attr({
              stroke: 'black',
              'stroke-width': 1
            }).add();

            renderer.text('Some text...', 30, 400).add();
          }
        }
      },
      legend: {
        y: -220
      },
      credits: {
        position: {
          y: -220
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

Comment: hi, @Kamil how to create the text on top, out of highcharts

Comment: I suppose, that would be very hard without modifying Highcharts core code. Have you considered simply applying `chart.marginTop`, moving the title down and rendering the custom text in the original position of the title (top of the chart)?
*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xa7vgz01/

Answer (score 2):

With Highcharts 7.2.0 you can add a `caption` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/caption)) besides the chart which is included in the export.

For example ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kf473mo2/)):

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [1, 4, 3, 5],
    }],
    caption: {
        text: '<b>Example</b><br><em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</em>'
    }
});
```

Comment: Or you can include the caption only in the export by specifying them in the exporting:{chartOptions:...}} override - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions